# Find the sum of the series: $\sum_{n=5}^{\infty} \frac{6}{n^2 - 3n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, indefinite-integrals, divergent-series

In terms of finding the sum of the series $\sum_{n=5}^{\infty} \frac{6}{n^2 - 3n}$ , this series looks to me like it is telescoping. So, I tried to factor it in a way to find a telescoping pattern, but I was unable to.

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions, *then* telescoping?

Comment: This is indeed telesoping through partial fraction decomposition (PFD first of course). Why don't you show us what you did before a ton of people are going to answer this for you?

Answer (score 9):

$\dfrac{6}{n(n-3)} = \dfrac{A}{n}+\dfrac{B}{n-3}$

$A(n-3) +Bn = 6$

$A = -2, B = 2$

This gives you:

$$\sum_{n=5}^\infty \left( \dfrac{2}{n-3}-\dfrac{2}{n} \right)$$

Comment: $=2\left(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)=2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)$